# Check folder periodically for changes and run script on OS X?

Tags: macos, script

I have a folder of files.  I would like for the system to check this folder every X minutes to see if any of the files have changed and, if so, to then run a script that I've written in python.

Comment: You can write a Python|shell script that calls your script on the folder, then sleeps for X minutes. For persistence, you can use either `launchd` or `cron`.

Comment: The problem is that I do not what the script to run *every* X minutes, only after X minutes and when the files have been modified.

Comment: That's what you would be doing? Sleep for X minutes; check if the files have been modified; call the other script if they have; rinse and repeat.

Comment: See DDay's answer on the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Python for the script, take a look at [Watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/).
You can easily install it with PIP, and the link provides a code sample.